Enter coordinates in georeferencer QGIS 3.34 by copying - pasting coordinates from Google Earth
i want to copy the coordinates taken from Google Earth App and paste them in the window "Enter Map Coordinates" in QGIS when i add a point (while georeferencing an image extracted from Google Earth).
I want the coordinates to be in decimal degrees. But when i copy the number from Google Earth, i cannot paste it. It seems that QGIS only accepts two decimals dd.dd, but when i just write it manually, it accepts the full number (6 decimals).
What is the problem?

Are you on the web version of Google Earth or the desktop?
